# Check if value in an array using Yup and React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

I have a StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-asoq6s?file=App.tsx,style.css)

It's a simple single input field with a submit button and yup validation to make the input required.

I also have an array of names.

I would like to check the name in the input field against this array and error if the name is not in the array.

I haven't attempted anything because I'm not sure where to start

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from 'yup';

interface User {
  firstname: string;
  singleErrorInput: string;
}

const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'Mike', 'Adam'];

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  firstname: yup.string().required('First Name Required'),
});

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<User>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const submitForm = (data: User): void => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            name="firstname"
            placeholder="Firstname"
            {...register('firstname')}
          />
          <input type="submit" />
          {errors.firstname && (
            <div className="error">{errors.firstname.message}</div>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `test` function to check whether the provided value is in the `names` array.

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  firstname: yup.string().test({
    message: () => 'must be in names array!',
    test(value) {
      return names.includes(value);
    },
  }).required('First Name Required'),
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-w2ut2k?file=App.tsx,index.tsx